# Javascript not reading the correct height from Samsung Galaxy Android tablet

Tags: javascript, android-browser

I'm trying to read the window size with javascript and this works fine for every platform I have tested except Android. I'm resizing div's based on this number so every div would fill the screen. On android, the first page looks fine,but as soon als you scroll down  it looks like the height was mesured without the height of the address-bar. So I end up with pages that are 50px short, showing the next page already.

This is the code i'm using to get the height & width of the platform:

```
app.tab1.sections.fitScreen = function(){
    var w = $(window).outerWidth(),
        h = $(window).outerHeight();

    //Fit all page-containers
    $('#tab1 .page-container').width(w).height( h );

    //Fit the first one(includes the header)
    $('#tab1 #page_1').height( h - ( $('#p-header').outerHeight() + $('#product-navigation').outerHeight() ) );
}
```

This screenshot illustrates the issue:
http://www.imgjoe.com/x/export03.png